# HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error Unable to place a FastCGI process in a JobObject. Try disabling the Application Pool CPU Limit feature

Tags: python, django, iis, application-pool, wfastcgi

I am trying to run my Django project on an IIS server using wfastcgi. I keep getting this error.  I have tried adjusting the CPU limit settings for the Application pool but this error is still occurring.  How can I completely disable the CPU Limit feature?

My config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Python FastCGI"
           path="*"
           verb="*"
           modules="FastCgiModule"
           scriptProcessor="C:\users\a0232200\python36\python.exe|c:\users\a0232200\python36\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py"
           resourceType="Unspecified"
           requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <appSettings>
    <!-- Required settings -->
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="project.wsgi.application" />
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\project" />

  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I have given read and execute access to the application pool tied to my Python36 directory.  I have read that wfastcgi and cpu limits are mutually exclusive but the error is suggesting that I need to disable the limiting feature.

[image]

[image]

Comment: wfastcgi issues should be reported to Microsoft via GitHub repo https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues

Comment: Microsoft also deprecated relevant Python extensions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service?view=vs-2017 and urged its users to move to Linux for Python app hosting, so you should switch to Linux too.